# Java Class isntance(with ToString method overriding) outputs "adt.BinaryNode@1e24e45"

Tags: java, string, instance

Hello i have overriden `toString()` method in my own class, but somehow the output is not exactly the one I wanted. Sorry for the newbie question but i cant figure out where the problem is, any  hint / help is mostly appreciated. Thank you.

Myclass:

```
public class Country implements Comparable<Country>{
    private String name;
    private String capital;
    private int area;

    public Country(String a, String b, int c) {
        this.name = a;
        this.capital = b;
        this.area =c;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return(this.name + " "+ this.capital+" " + this.area);
    }
}
```

DS:

```
private void  preorder(BinaryNode  <type>  a){
      if (a != null){
       System.out.println(a.toString());
       preorder(a.left);
       preorder(a.right );
      }
}
```

App:

```
BinarySearchTree <Country> db = new BinarySearchTree<Country>();
    Country ob  = new Country("Romania", "Buc", 123);
    db.addNewElement(ob);
        ob  = new Country("Hungaria", "Bud", 50);
    db.addNewElement(ob);
        ob  = new Country("Vatican", "Vat", 1);
    db.addNewElement(ob);
    db.printAll();
```

output:

```
adt.BinaryNode@1e5e2c3
adt.BinaryNode@18a992f
adt.BinaryNode@4f1d0d
```

EDIT: fix after "chaitanya10" hint  for msitake

DS:

```
private void  preorder(BinaryNode  <type>  a){
      if (a != null){
       System.out.println(a.elm.toString()); // ACCES the data in node not the hole node.
       preorder(a.left);
       preorder(a.right );
      }
}
```

Comment: What 3rd party library does `BinarySearchTree` come from?  That's where the problem is.

Comment: noop fixed, needet to `nod.element.toString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your method takes `BinaryNode<type>` as an `argument`, you are calling `toString` on `brinaryNode<type>` not `COuntry`. you have `overriden toString()` in `Country` not `BinaryTree`.
change it to

```
private void  preorder(Country a){
      if (a != null){
       System.out.println(a.toString());

      }
}
```

OR
 `override toString() in BinaryNode`.

Comment: `preorder` is a method of `BinarySearchTree` it can't be implemented specifically to `Country`... or am I missing something?

Comment: @JuanMendes tbh, i amnot familiar with BinaryTree methods, i was just pointing out what his mistake was :)

Comment: @BogdanM. thanks :) and i hope you are overriding toString() in BinaryNode :)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the toString method of BinaryNode, not Country